# CartoDB - visualise multiple properties

Tags: carto, clustering, visualisation

Is there a clever way to visualise more than one property in a single map overlay?

Ideally I would like to produce a dot grid map in which the size of the dot represents a scaled property and the colour range would represent a second property of the same feature.

[image]

As an alternative this could be achieved by using clustering.

There is a [CartoDB clustering example](http://bl.ocks.org/andrewxhill/8675947). However, this example doesn't really show how to apply a scaled size based on an aggregated property. There is also no colour based on an aggregated property.

Maybe someone can nudge me in the right direction to show an aggregated property in a hexagon map. The CartoDB wizard has only an option to display point density.

```
#admin_soa_pop{
  [points_density <= 0.00000416004431488379] { polygon-fill: #BD0026;  }
  [points_density <= 3.71432528114624e-7] { polygon-fill: #F03B20;  }
  [points_density <= 1.4857301124585e-7] { polygon-fill: #FD8D3C;  }
  [points_density <= 7.42865056229248e-8] { polygon-fill: #FECC5C;  }
  [points_density <= 7.42865056229248e-8] { polygon-fill: #FFFFB2;  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do can be archived using CartoCSS.

So, assuming you are using CartoDB Editor:

- Select the bubble wizard and set the column, quantification and size parameters for the bubble visualization
- Then go to CartoCSS and add the code to classify by `column2` with different colors:
  `#table_name[column2=value]{marker-fill:#HEX;}`
  You can add as many CSS rules as categories you want to make on `column2`.